# How to pick/read data from .pdf file using vb 6.0 with ado

Tags: vb6, pdf-generation

i need a vb code for this
want to read data from .pdf file using vb6 as front end as ms access as a backend

thanks regards

Nasir

Answer (score 0):

To use ADO to read data from a .pdf file you would need an OLE DB provider for pdf or an ODBC driver for pdf. I am almost sure you won't find one because a .pdf file will rarely contain suitable data i.e. tables of rows of columns etc.